# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, python-2.x

I'm very new to Python and I was wondering if anyone could help me with this code I wrote:

```
print("What is your name:")
name = raw_input()
print "hi", name, "How are you:"
Feeling = raw_input()
if Feeling ("good"):
   print ("Good")
Else
print ("Thats a shame")
```

It just comes up with error this when I run it:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have looked online but I couldn't find anything that would help because the answers were to complex.

Could someone please help me.

Comment: How I would play:
 >What is your name:
 > Kieveli
 >hi Kieveli How are you:
 > FANTANTILLYDILLYASTIC!
 >Thats a shame

Comment: @Kieveli: Yes, that is a bit of a shame. Maybe you can see a speech therapist. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use the string stored in `Feeling` as a function.

```
if Feeling ("good"):
```

With nothing but spaces between `Feeling` and the parenthesis around `"good"`, Python sees that as a function call.

You probably wanted to test if it was equal to `"good"` instead:

```
if Feeling == "good":
     print "Good"
```

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
if Feeling ("good"):
```

You're trying to call `Feeling` as a function, with `"good"` as an argument. That's what parentheses mean in this syntax.

If you want to check whether `Feeling` *is equal to* `"good"`, you use the `==` operator:

```
if Feeling == "good":
```

Meanwhile, as soon as you fix that, you're going to have another problem with the next line:

```
Else
```

In Python, capitalization counts; `else` has to be spelled in all lowercase. Also, block statements (like `if` and `else`) always need colons. And the statements inside a block statement have to be indented. So, you want this:

```
else:
    print("Thats a shame")
```

You may want to find a smarter editor that helps you with some of this stuff, instead of using Notepad/TextEdit/etc. Any decent programmer's editor—including free ones like SciTE or emacs—will try to put the cursor at the right place for indentation, highlight when you've made a syntax error, and so on.

Comment: Im not using notepad im using IDLE

Comment: Since't the OP is using python 2.x, perhaps they should use `print "That's a shame"` and avoid the parentheses.

Comment: @SethMMorton: There's no reason to change the parts of his code that already work properly when there's more than enough to explain already.

Comment: @abarnert  OK.  I was just concerned because they were mixing and matching so I didn't want there to be confusion later on.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Yeah, it's worth having as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
if Feeling ("good"):
```

`Feeling` is a string, the result of raw_input(). Feeling("good") looks like you want to call it as if it were a function. That's not possible, so it says "str object is not callable".

You probably meant

```
if Feeling == "good":
```

You're also missing a `:` after the `else`, you shouldn't capitalize else, and the line after should be indented.